# Is it possible to steal money from an account/card by knowing only the card number and PIN?

Tags: bank-account, fraud, security, atm, password

I have an ATM card, it is a local bank issued card without any international payment service like Visa, MasterCard or such. If someone knows only the **16 numbers on the card** and the **PIN** (and also perhaps, **my name**), would they be able to steal money from my account linked to the card? Maybe by card cloning or some other methods?

**The card is always in my possession**, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

If your card is always in your possession, the attacker won't have your CVC1/CVV1 which is embeded in the Magnetic Stripe of your card. This number is different from CVC2/CVV2 printed at the back of your card.

Cash Withdrawal at ATM is an "Online" transaction, in which the ATM and your Bank would perform verification in real-time. That is when CVC1/CVV1 is verified.

Nonetheless, some Internet banking portal allows reset of Internet banking password using 16-digit card number and the card PIN. This would potentially be a successful attack.

Comment: And for people in countries where the magnetic stripe is as forgotten as [punched-hole cash-cards](https://www.rbs.com/heritage/rbs-history-in-100-objects/history-in-100-themes/serving-our-customers/cash-card-1969.html), the equivalent of reading the CVV1/CVC1  is handled by communicating with the chip embedded into any card manufactured since late in the prior millenium. Usually by non-contact means (e.g. RFID for card, NFC for phone)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick To be fair, EMV Chip card also comes with magnetic stripe. Although cash withdrawal cannot be conducted using that magnetic stripe in countries that have already popularized EMV, that magnetic stripe can be used in countries where EMV is not supported. Paneroid people can degauss their EMV card with magnets.